# Show catched JSON object from PHP in android application

Tags: java, php, android, json

I'm going to create a simple register form app that when user insert their **username** and **password**, **EditText** in UI shows the **id** of their record in database.

My app insert users into database correctly and show **JSON output** into **EditText**.

For Example when I insert first user to my database, **EditText** show this:

```
{
    "id": "1", "0":"1"
}
```

But, I want show this in **EditText**:

**1** instead of 
    { 
        "id" : "1", "0" : "1" 
    }

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#00aeef"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="Register Example"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:text="Username:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_username"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:ems="10"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_insert"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_result"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edt_password"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:text="Insert"
    android:textColor="#00aeef" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edt_username"
    android:text="Password:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_password"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_username"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:ems="10"
    android:padding="5dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_insert"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:ems="10"
    android:padding="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**InsertClass.java**

```
package com.example.testphp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class InsertClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

private Context context;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private EditText edt;
private String json = "";   
private JSONObject jObj = null;

public InsertClass(Context context, EditText edt)
{
    this.context = context;
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    this.edt = edt;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading... Please wait");
    pDialog.show();
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

    try
    {
    String username = (String)arg0[0];
    String password = (String)arg0[1];
    String link = "http://10.0.2.2:8020/test/test.php";
    String data = URLEncoder.encode("username","utf-8") + 
    "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username,"utf-8");
    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password","utf-8") + 
            "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password,"utf-8");
    URL url = new URL(link);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(data);
    wr.flush();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        sb.append(line);
        break;
    }
    json = sb.toString();
    jObj = new JSONObject(json);

    return sb.toString();
    }
    catch(JSONExeption e)
    {
        return new String("Exeption: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return new String("Exeption: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    pDialog.dismiss();
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    try
    {
       edt.setText(jObj.getString("id"));
    }
    catch (JSONExeption e)
    { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.testphp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String username;
String password;
EditText edtUsername;
EditText edtPassword;
EditText edtResult;
Button btnInsert;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnInsert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_insert);
    edtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_password);
    edtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_username);
    edtResult = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_result);

    btnInsert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            username = edtUsername.getText().toString();
            password = edtPassword.getText().toString();
            new InsertClass(MainActivity.this, edtResult).execute(username,password);

        }
    });

}

    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**test.PHP**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost" , "root" , "","test");
if(mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
} 
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO test (username,pass) VALUES '$username','$password')") or die(mysqli_query($con));

if($result)
{
    $id_result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM test WHERE username = '$username'") or die(mysqli_query($con));

    if($id_result)
    {
        $id_result = mysqli_fetch_array($id_result);
        $response = array("id" => $id_result);
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Any suggestion, would be appreciated ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response from PHP for user id=17 is {"id":{"0":"17","id":"17"}} 
Try to change in php script

```
//$response = array("id" => $id_result);
$response["id"] = $id_result["id"];
```

then your rsponse will be {"id":"17"}

Answer (score 0):

In your class `InsertClass` and function `doInBackground()` where you are converting result string to JsonObject like

```
json = sb.toString();
jObj = new JSONObject(json);
```

Add code:

```
String result = jObj.getString ("id");
Return result;
```

Comment: I've used edt.setText(jObj.getString("id")) in onPostExecute ...
My wrong was in PHP codes ... Tanks for you answer